# price check by product if not available get category price else product price - mysql query needed

Tags: php, mysql

category table and product table schema are given below and result structure given.

product table:

```
category id | product id
-------------------------
1           :  1  
1           :  2  
1           :  3
```

price table :

```
category id | product id | price
--------------------------------- 
1           |    NULL    |  10.00  
1           |    3       |  15.00
```

REsULT:

```
category id | product id | price
---------------------------------
1           :  1     : 10.00  
1           :  2     : 10.00  
1           :  3     : 15.00
```

i need mysql query for this condition. please help me i running out of ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your product table and price table can combine into one table. product(category_id,product_id,price,prod_name,date_created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lengthy approach but result is same as desired.

```
SELECT c.categoryid, c.productid, price 
FROM cat c 
JOIN link l USING(categoryid) WHERE l.productid IS NOT NULL AND l.productid<=>c.productid
UNION

SELECT c.categoryid, c.productid, price
FROM cat c 
JOIN link l USING(categoryid)
WHERE L.productid IS NULL AND c.productid NOT IN(
SELECT DISTINCT c.productid
FROM cat c 
JOIN link l USING(categoryid)
    WHERE l.productid IS NOT NULL AND l.productid<=>c.productid
    )
```

Validate here as [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da75fc/1)

Comment: thanks for the queries, it helps to create a view using MySQL queries, no other looping